# Convert value in decimal digit result

Tags: xquery

Looking for your expert help where I am getting a number as 2 but would like to have that displayed as 2.0 where as if its 2.5 then this is fine, I would like to display 2.5 only.

I am using xquery version "1.0";

I am trying to use format-number function but seems like this not supported with version 1.0

```
<ns0:value>{data($InputNumber/ns0:count)}</ns0:value>
```

where if count is 2
then it should display as

```
<ns0:value>2.0</ns0:value>
```

and if count is a decimal value as 2.5 then it should be the way it is

kindly advise

Comment: Is that typed input with schema-aware XQuery 1 so that `data($InputNumber/ns0:count)` returns a numeric value? Or is it untyped input so that you get an xs:untypedAtomic? In the first case you can simply test `let $c := data($InputNumber/ns0:count) return if ($c instance of xs:integer) then concat($c, '.0') else $c`, in the second you can still use `castable as` e.g. `let $c := data($InputNumber/ns0:count) return if ($c castable as xs:integer) then concat($c, '.0') else $c`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check whether the input string contains a dot and otherwise append `.0` at the end :

```
let $in:=data($InputNumber/ns0:count)
return if (contains($in, '.')) then $in else concat($in, '.0')
```

Comment: Thanks for help but dont we have nay inbuild function available in Xquery to do so. like we have number format

Comment: @kumarb I'm not sure what you mean, both `contains` and `concat` are implemented in XQuery 1.0 ([`contains`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-contains) & [`concat`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-concat) in the [XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Functions and Operators](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/))